# Finding the widest acceptable ranges for x of given y while meeting certain criteria

Tags: python

I am thinking about a problem for some time now and it would be awesome if someone could give me advice how to solve it (I prefer python).

Given are 8 equitations (y1 to y8) with 5 independent variables x1, x2, x3, x4, x5. The functions look like this:

```
y1 = f(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) = a*x1 + b*x2 + c*x3 + d*x4 + e*x5 + a*x1*x2 + b*b*x2 + c*c*x3
y2 = f(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) = f*x1 + g*x2 + h*x5 + a*a*x1 + d*d*x4 ...
y3 = f(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) = ...
...
y8 = f(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) = i*x1 + k*x3 + l*x5 + j*j*x2*x2 + c*c*x3 + ...
```

As you can see they only share the same x1,x2,x3,x4,x5, but the coefficients are all different. The number of terms can be different too.

The range of each variable x allowed to be used in y is restricted to:

```
x1 = (1,10) #any float between 1 and 10 can be used
x2 = (10,20)
x3 = (100,200)
x4 = (50,80)
x5 = (20,50)
```

The goal is to find the 'widest' ranges for each of the 5 independent variables that will meet the following criteria:
y1 must not by lower than 10,
y2 must not by lower than 7,
y3 must not by lower than 20 ... So basically each y has to yield a specified minium value. This means for every combination of x1,x2,x3,x4,x5 all 8 equitations need to be calculated and checked whether all y1 to y8 fulfill the criteria.

One solution for the 5 ranges could be:

```
x1 = (3,7)
x2 = (14,15)
x3 = (111,130)
x4 = (60,65)
x5 = (20,22)
```

but the following solution would be better because the ranges are wider:

```
x1 = (2,10) # 10-2 = 8. This is a wider range than the x1 example above (7-3 = 4)
x2 = (11,19)
x3 = (104,190)
x4 = (51,78)
x5 = (21,49)
```

How can I find the widest ranges for each x while meeting the y criteria? How would you solve this or at least try to find the best solution? Brute forcing all the combinations cannot be done in acceptable time.

Comment: Since you say "_I prefer python_", I have removed the other language tags. Please choose only the tag for the language that you are actually working with or maybe `language-agnostic` as an alternative. Tagging multiple languages is likely to get you downvotes.

Comment: I suspect that this can be nicely approached using linear programming

Comment: @Ben Grossmann not all the terms are linear, sadly.

Comment: It looks like they're linear with respect to x1,...,x5, which is the only linearity that matters in this context

Comment: @BenGrossmann I can see a (x2*x2) term in there.

Comment: @AKareem You're right I missed that

Comment: Are x's always positive? More generally, it would help if all f functions were convex. If so, you could pose this as a nonlinear constrained maximization problem: define two variables per x interval, a lower and an upper bound. Then maximize the sum of interval lengths subject to lower bounds on y's and interval constraints on x's. You could use Pyomo for Python of JuMP for Julia to try out this approach.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem x's can be positive and negative. I will have a look at pyomo, thank you.